# Cordova file transfer upload error code 1

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am using cordova file transfer to upload an image to server. The problem is cordova file transfer always throwing **error code 1**. It worked before suddenly today it stop working.

I dont see any param options value received on server.
My code

```
savebase64AsImageFile(folderpath,filename,realData,dataType,q).then(function (success){
    console.log(success);
    $cordovaFile.checkFile(folderpath, filename).then(function (success) {
            console.log(success);
            success.getMetadata(function(metadata) {
            console.log('meta size2 ' +metadata.size); 
        });
    }, function (error) {

});
$scope.data.image = filename;
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(encodeURI(server), filePath, options, true).then(function(result) {...
```

I already checked using $cordovaFile.checkFile to make sure the file exists.
and the options

```
var options ={
        fileName: filename,
        chunkedMode: true,
        params:{'user_id' : $scope.data.userid},
        headers:{Connection: 'close'}
    };
```

On my server I am using Laravel but the $request data is empty, I cant access the file or the user_id.

For the folderpath I am using this

```
var folderpath = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
var filePath = folderpath + filename;
```

filepath will return file location

> file:///data/user/0/com.ionicframework.test3829076/files/PV5xo1506004208779.jpg

I am testing this on android device

File Transfer Error
[image]

status 409 is number I am giving if the request is null

Any idea what cause this error?
This part of code always worked before.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you have your parameters backwards. it's upload(filepath, server, etc.)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading without the options or use

```
var options ={
    fileName: filename,
    chunkedMode: false,
    params:{'user_id' : $scope.data.userid},
    headers:{Connection: 'close'}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Code 1 can be the access issue.
In my case there was a problem with file permissions.
If you use sdk version less then 29 (android 10) you have to force user to give read permission

add cordova-plugin-android-permissions in config.xml

```
const filesPermissions = (permissions) => [
 permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
 permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
];

const checkFilesPermissions = async () => {
  const { permissions } = window.cordova.plugins;
  return Promise.all(filesPermissions(permissions).map(permission => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => permissions.checkPermission(permission, resolve, reject));
  })).then(statuses => statuses.every(status => status.hasPermission));
};

const requestFilesPermissions = async () => {
    const { permissions } = window.cordova.plugins;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        permissions.requestPermissions(filesPermissions(permissions), resolve, reject);
  }).then(status => status.hasPermission);
};
```

// onClickHandler:

```
if (deviceService.isAndroidPlatform()) {
  try {
    let hasFilesPermissions = await checkFilesPermissions();
    if (!hasFilesPermissions) {
      hasFilesPermissions = await requestFilesPermissions();
    }
    if (!hasFilesPermissions) {
      throw new Error('There is no permissions to download files. Please enable it in system preferences');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message)
  }
}
```

// and then just upload your file using cordova-plugin-file-transfer as usual

Note: you have to enable READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your AndroidManifest.xml